# Will orc camps be more hospitable towards the Dragonborn if he or she is an orsimer?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so I am planning on starting a new game. Since I find myself going into a full blown frenzy of sword and dagger and prefer mercenary work, I believe the perfect race for this would be either redguard, nord, or Orc. Well I've played both Nord and Redguard in the past. So I'm gonna play the Orc. However, let's say I go to Largashbur. Will the Orc clan there be more inclined to welcome me in or will I still be viewed as an outsider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the UESP article on [Orc Strongholds](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Orc_Strongholds):

> Only [Orc](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Orc) characters have immediate access to the strongholds unchallenged. Characters of any other race must first become [Blood-Kin of the Orcs](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood-Kin_of_the_Orcs) before being welcome in the strongholds. Without being Blood-Kin, you can enter a stronghold, but everyone will continuously tell you that you are not welcome, and you are unable to trade with any merchants in the stronghold.

So you will be welcomed in the Orc strongholds immediately if you are an Orc. You will be able to trade with their vendors and talk to everyone without being told to leave. If you want the orcs to do any favors for you, however, some of them still have quests that they ask you to go on.